# optical thickness of a supernova

Tags: astrophysics, radiative-transfer

I need to explain this question to a bunch of students tomorrow and I am not 100% sure how to solve it myself..Help would be much appreciated. The question is.

> If a Classical Nova ejects $10^{−5}$ $M_\odot$ of Hydrogen rich material over the
>   course of a day at velocities of 5,000 km/s, show that the maximum
>   extent of the Pseudo-Photosphere is ∼ 1 AU. You may assume that the
>   opacity is dominated by Thompson/Electron scattering ($\tilde{\kappa}$ = 0.2 (1 + X)
>   cm$^2$/g).

So the density is relatively easy as we can assume that it is expelling at a constant rate. So we divide the mass by the # seconds in a day and get a number for the mass expulsion rate $m$. The density at one point is $\rho = m/4$pi$r^2$ so we can integrate the density over the LOS to get the amount of material. M = $\int^\infty_r rho$. But how do we get a tau out of this? I'm also not sure how the $\kappa$ is used here, since we do not know X. Once that is known, its just a matter of calculating for $\tau=1.$

Comment: @RobJeffries - you could do this

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Hint: what is the relationship between optical depth and opacity.

Comment: Hint 2: What is the definition of X?